# What and how do derivate?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

How do I derive this function?

$f(x) = x(e^{-x^2})$

I need the first and second derivative.

Comment: Hi, check out our advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). If you literally need the derivatives and nothing else, Wolfram Alpha will do the job. If you'd like the process made clear to you, you should say what is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use product rule then chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

First, remember the product and chain rules:

> *Product/Leibniz Rule*: $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$
>
> *Chain Rule*: $(f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)g'$

First, we have to see what are the "outernmost" simple functions in the definition of $f(x)=x\cdot e^{-x^2}$: If we let $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=e^{-x^2}$, then $f=gh$, so using the product rule:
$$f'(x)=g'(x)h(x)+g(x)h'(x)$$
In the equation above, you know $g(x)$, $g'(x)$, and $h(x)$, sothe problem is to calculate $h'(x)$. Notice that $h'(x)=e^{-x^2}$. Letting $i(x)=e^x$ and $j(x)=-x^2$, then $h=i\circ j$, so, by the chain rule,
$$h'(x)=i'(j(x))\cdot j'(x)$$
and you probably know the values of $i'(y)$ and $j'(x)$. Use the two equations above and find $f'(x)$.